# Children's novel about a boy who buys a device from an old man and travels to a parallel universe

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, parallel-universe

I'm trying to remember a book I read in the late 1970s. It was about a boy who goes to this wild old man's shop and buys a device (I remember it being kind of like a transistor radio). When he uses the device as he's walking along he unexpectedly shifts into a parallel universe. I seem to remember something about lizard people and perhaps motorcycles, but I could be wrong about that. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds a bit like some stuff by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Pinkwater

Comment: Oh my gosh. You (and the internet) are amazing. I found it!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Mendelsohn,_the_Boy_from_Mars

Comment: Please make your comments into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Per Phil's (own) comment, the book described is "[Alan Mendelsohn, The Boy from Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Mendelsohn,_the_Boy_from_Mars)" by Daniel M. Pinkwater

[image: The Boy from Mars]